# Using a 'for' loop in C# to fill picturebox number 'i' with an image

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, controls

I have six Pictureboxes and a `for` loop. I'd like to refer to PictureBox with the same number as 'i' variable that's being incremented inside a `for` loop.

For example, if the 'i' variable from my `for` loop is 2 I'd like to assign an image to picturebox2.

How do I do this the easiest way? It is a unique way that also works for other controls (that is, labels, textboxes) would be nice. :)

Answer (score 4):

Put references to the controls in an array:

```
PictureBox[] boxes = {
  PictureBox1, PictureBox2, PictureBox3, PictureBox4, PictureBox5, PictureBox6
};
```

Then you can loop through them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < boxes.Length; i++) {
  // use boxes[i] to access each picture box
}
```

Comment: I've tried this before but I get 

`Error 2 The name 'PictureBox2' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @HolyGoat - This answer would work - but you may need to define your array using `pictureBox2` rather than `PictureBox2`. Note the difference between camel case and pascal case.

Comment: @HolyGoat: Check what the id of the control really is. If `PictureBox1` is accessible but not `PictureBox2`, then it suggests that the scope is right, but there isn't actually any picture box with the id `PictureBox2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Tag` property of any control to provide additional info (like image name or index). E.g. you can provide index for your pictureBoxes. Also use ImageList to store list of images:

```
foreach(var pictureBox in Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
{
    if (pictureBox.Tag == null) // you can skip other pictureBoxes
        continue;

    int imageIndex = (int)pictureBox.Tag;
    pictureBox.Image = imageList.Images[imageIndex];
}
```

Also you can search picture box by tag value:

```
var pictureBox = Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()
                         .FirstOrDefault(pb => (int)pb.Tag == index);
```

---

Another option - if all your pictureBoxes have names like `pictureBox{index}`. In this case you can go without usage of Tag:

```
var pictureBox = Controls
  .OfType<PictureBox>()                     
  .FirstOrDefault(pb => Int32.Parse(pb.Name.Replace("pictureBox", "")) == index);
```

Comment: I understand imagelist idea, I don't understand how to use tag property to i.e. fill picturebox3 with image if for loop iterator == 3 though.

Comment: There is two options - either provide Tag from code `pictureBox1.Tag = 1`, or from designer - select pictureBox and set it's Tag property. But in second case Tag will contain string! Be careful.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky kinda irrelevant: can you please provide the code using the Tag for visual c++? thank you

Comment: @AlaaM. unfortunately last time I used C++ was about 10 years ago. So I think you will handle this task better than me :)

Answer (score 1):

I implement this with Array of PictureBoxes :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ImageChanger
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        PictureBox[] pictureBoxs=new PictureBox[4];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            pictureBoxs[0] = pictureBox1;
            pictureBoxs[1] = pictureBox2;
            pictureBoxs[2] = pictureBox3;
            pictureBoxs[3] = pictureBox4;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                // Load Image from Resources
                pictureBoxs[i].Image = Properties.Resources.img100;

                Application.DoEvents();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this before but I get `Error 2 The name 'PictureBox2' does not exist in the current context`